# XCOPY overwrite action?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, xcopy

in the bat file I got a simply command like :

```
xcopy "C:\Users\me\Documents\ApplyPatchBat" "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Test\" /S/E/K
```

This does the job where it will copy all the files including files inside subfolders. I know you can add /y to make it auto overwrite. 
How ever I want to create an statement if this file that we are copying exist in the destination folder, copy the one in destination folder to a backup folder.

I wonder there is any IF statement I can add to after the command to detect if the file is existing? Or maybe an error level check when its asking do I want to overwrite? 
P.S. This is for applying new patches to a program, where there are many layers of folders, that's why I use the /S/E/K  in xcopy.

Comment: That can't be done in xcopy - you can use a script to check and move the files prior to xcopy running.

Comment: you should better use a [VCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_revision_control_software), if you want to track revisions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xcopy itself can't backup beforehand, but with output from xcopy and a bit of for loop magic you can make this happen

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set source="C:\Users\me\Documents\ApplyPatchBat"
set target="C:\Users\me\Desktop\Test\"

rem /l = list only, /u = already existing, /y = yes to replace
rem /f = display full source and destination file names, /c = continue on errors
rem /s = subdirectories, /k = keep attributes
rem split the strings at ->, we're only interested in the part after ->
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,* delims=>" %%a in (`xcopy %source% %target% /l /u /y /f /c /s /k`) do (
    set file=%%b
    rem ignore lines without a destination, e.g. 15 file(s) copied
    if x!file! neq x (
        rem remove the leading space, original string is source -> destination
        set file=!file:~1!
        for %%f in ("!file!") do (
            if not exist %%~dpf\backup\* md %%~dpf\backup
            rem only backup if not already backed up
            if not exist %%~dpf\backup\%%~nxf move %%f %%~dpf\backup
        )
    )
)
xcopy %source% %target% /y /c /q /s /k
```

Comment: This is amazing, much optimized than what I am trying to do. just a few questions in order to fully understand it. In the first, does the xcopy inside the bracket actually copy the files ? so %%a will be the files? What will %%b be ? And the last question, what does x!file! neq x mean ? Thank you so much for the help tho !

Comment: The first xcopy has the /l flag which just lists the files without copying. The tokens=1,* will make %%a the source (with a trailing " -" space dash) and %%b the destination (with a leading space). The enabledelayedexpansion allows you to use ! in place of % for variables, but using ! means that the values refresh. So x!file! equ x is asking - is !file! blank?

Comment: Thanks thats more clear now :) I know that temp var ! sign, but what does the 2 x around the statement mean ?

Comment: This might help explain this part for you: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php